# List three latest files in a directory in linux in the commandline?

Tags: linux, command-line, alias

I was thinking of adding a convenience alias for myself. As of right now I have an alias called `ll` for `ls -lha`.

However, I noticed there were several occasions where I wanted to list the latest three files in a directory. This can be tedious in the console, especially when the directory contains hundreds of files.

Usually, one can do:

```
ll -1t | head -3
```

However, this is still a bit tedious, as it requires filtering. `ll` prints the total file size as top line. And then it followed either by `.` or `..` or both, which would make sense to filter out as well. Is there a nice way to do that?

Is it possible to make dynamic aliases, say `lll{0-n}`, so, if I type `lll7` it would list the 7 latest files in a directory, starting with the latest one on top?

Comment: Alias works by simply replacing *text*. More information [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/108618).

Comment: Alright, fair. That means I am limited to a hard coded limit, which is fine, I guess. But I am still unsure about the filtering issue.

Comment: Hardcoded? No. One can create a shell function or a script that takes argument(s) and applies logic. My point is the alias is not the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, you can create this function (put it in your `~/.bashrc`, then source it):

```
function lll { ls -at1 | grep -v -e '^\.$' -e '^\.\.$' | head -$1 ; }
```

To display the most recent 7 files from newest to oldest, not including `.` nor `..`, type this at the bash prompt:

```
lll 7
```